# Replace entire page contents (with DOCTYPE)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I know that this question has been asked before, but most answers only replaced the body tag, or needed jQuery. I want to be able to replace the entire page contents **including the DOCTYPE** using plain JavaScript. Also, I don't want to redirect the page with `window.location.href`. Take this simple page (index.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Testing...</p>
</body>

</html>
```

After loading another page with AJAX:

```js
var page;
var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
file.open('GET', './toload.html');
file.onreadystatechange = function() {
  page = file.responseText;
}
file.send();
```

I want to erase my current page contents and display the contents of `toload.html`, which is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Loaded</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello. This page is now loaded!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `document.write(page);` will do it. Is there any reason your not using an ajax framework? If you were to use JQuery you could do `$('html').html(page);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing Entire Page Including Head Using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292603/replacing-entire-page-including-head-using-javascript)

Comment: @AndyRay I have read that page, but I don't think any of those methods also replace the DOCTYPE.

Comment: @Edward `document.write(page);` apparently doesn't have full browser compatibility.

Comment: @Edward Also, the jQuery method only changes the html content, not the entire page.

Comment: `document.write` was one of the first things added to the DOM. Where are you finding limited compatibility? Otherwise, you'd have to literally build the DOM manually, using DOM methods like: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8227612/215552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I decided I could just replace the content inside the `<html>` tags. The code I used was:

```
var contents = "Sorry : ( IMPORT FAILED...";
var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
file.open("GET", "/toload.html", false);
file.onreadystatechange = function() {
    contents = file.responseText;
}
file.send(null);
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = contents;
```

Thanks for your wonderful answers anyway!

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can get is:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML="";
```

Ill update this answer if I can find out why you can't clear the DOM's root node.

Answer (score 0):

Just use document.write()      ;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.